# Enviar bit para pinos específicos de porta paralela com php

Tags: php, porta-serial

Preciso enviar um bit (pulso) pra pinos específicos de uma porta paralela para controlar alguns motores de passo...

Com a classe php_serial.class.php eu sei como enviar uma string, mas como envio apenas um bit e pra especificamente uma porta? Seria possível?

```
$serial->deviceSet("COM6");
$serial->confBaudRate(9600);
$serial->confStopBits(1);
$serial->confCharacterLength(8);

$serial->deviceOpen();

$serial->sendMessage("\xFF\x01\x01");

$serial->deviceClose();
```

Comment: Douglas pelo que deu pra entender você está integrando com Arduíno ou Raspberry Pi, correto? Já trabalhei com Arduino e sei que é necessário integrar comandos que chegam pela serial (textão ou números mesmo) e então direcionar o sinal para a porta específica através do Arduíno.

Comment: na verdade, eu não vou enviar para nenhum dos 2, eu quero enviar para essa controladora de modelo: "hy-jk02-m 5-axis interface", mas não acho que ela tem um interpretador assim como o arduino, ela só recebe pulsos identificados pelos pinos da porta serial...

Comment: Douglas, desculpe... não possuo conhecimento específico nesta controladora para poder te ajudar. Talvez uma busca na documentação desta controladora (se houver) te ajude. Boa sorte!